# how to check whether string contains '@ 'and '.'?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
search_field : ________
```

In these field we can enter either name or email. Considering whether if the string contains `@` and `.`,it would be considered as email else name.

The code i tried is:

```
if(preg_match('[@|.]', $search_field )) {
    echo "email present";
} 
else{
  echo name present";
}
```

The formats wht i entered is:

`search_field : masn@`     .

it gave me output as email present but i want the output in the other way.It should show email presence one and only  if it contains both `@` and `.`

Comment: What exactly you want ??? if you are getting then what is the problem

Comment: one and only if the string contains @ and . i need output as email present else name present..!!!! can't u understand my que??

Comment: In your current search string you contain both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to validate the emails, then try this

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

If you want to validate name then use

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
if(preg_match('!@+!', $search_field )) {
    echo "email present";
} 
else{
  echo "name present";
}
```